# Tell Import-Module to run once

Tags: powershell

When using `Import-Module` to import Powershell in a script, how can I tell it to go ahead and actually import the modules, suppressing the confirmation message?

Is there a way to do this with `Set-ExecutionPolicy` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force
```

Will suppress the prompt for Set-ExecutionPolicy. There is no confirmation prompt for Import-Module, so there's nothing to do there.

`Get-Help <cmdlet> -full` is your friend.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was doing the Import first and then the Set-ExecutionPolicy second, which was stupid